# .htaccess RewriteRule not working after switching providers

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to have a short link for images hosted on my website. An example:

```
http://example.com/sharex/user/UUd.png
```

The short link:

```
i.example.com/nUUd
```

The subdomain "i" redirects to http://example.com/sharex, and the "n" character indicates the directory the file is stored in. The expected behaviour is to visit the short link, and view the image file hosted at the long link (without the URL changing in the browser).

Here's the .htaccess file I have in the /sharex/ directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^n(.*)$ /user/$1.png [P,L]
```

This issue presented itself after switching hosting providers, even though the *exact same thing* worked on my previous host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming your have `mod_proxy` correctly setup on new host.

Fix your `RewriteBase` and use a relative URI in target:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sharex/

RewriteRule ^n(.*)$ quartzic/$1.png [P,NC,L]
```

Comment: Well, I just figured out why this didn't work - apparently my new shared hosting provider doesn't support mod_proxy :( Thanks for your help anyways